# Getting an exception when calling Syscall function

Tags: c++, go, dll, ffi

I am using Go's syscall package to call a DLL that is written in C++.

C++ method signature looks like this.

`init(int* buffer, int argc, char* argv[], const char* fileName, const char* key, const char* prefix, const char* version)`

this is the function I am using to call above method in Go.

```
func init(
  buffer uintptr, 
  argsCount int, 
  args []string, 
  fileName string, 
  key string, 
  prefix string, 
  version string
) uintptr {
    // libHandle is handle to the loaded DLL
    methodAddress := getProcAddress(libHandle, "init")

    status, _, err := syscall.Syscall9(
      methodAddress,
      7,
      buffer,
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&argsCount)),
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&args)),
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(fileName))),
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(key))),
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(prefix))),
      uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(version))),
      0,
      0)

      fmt.Println(err.Error())

      return status
 }
```

I get this Error When I invoking this method and don't have an Idea about this.

```
Exception 0xc0000005 0x0 0x0 0x7fffe30bdb33
PC=0x7fffe30bdb33

syscall.Syscall9(0x7fffe32db600, 0x7, 0x97db50, 0xc00007ff10, 
0xc00007ff70, 0xc000054180, 0xc0000541a0, 0xc0000541c0, 0xc0000541e0, 
0x0, ...)

c:/go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:210 +0xf3
main.main()

 E:/Path/test.go:157 +0x2be
 rax     0x81fbf0
 rbx     0x1
 rcx     0x7ff804ad1310
 rdi     0x7ff10
 rsi     0xc00007ff70
 rbp     0x0
 rsp     0x81fbc0
 r8      0x0
 r9      0x7ff804ad0000
 r10     0xc00007ff00
 r11     0x81fbf0
 r12     0x7ff10
 r13     0xc00007ff70
 r14     0xc000054180
 r15     0x97db50
 rip     0x7fffe30bdb33
 rflags  0x10257
 cs      0x33
 fs      0x53
 gs      0x2b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The setting

So, basically, the mapping you've got is

1. `int* buffer` → `buffer uintptr`
2. `int argc` → `unsafe.Pointer(&argsCount)`, where `&argsCount` is a pointer to `int`
3. `char* argv[]` → `unsafe.Pointer(&args)`, where `args` is `[]string`
4. `const char* fileName` → `unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(fileName))`

   `const char* key`, `const char* prefix`, `const char* version` — same as above.

### The problems

Now what's wrong with this.

1. Passing `uintptr` values containing addresses of live Go objects between functions is prohibited. (More on this later.)
2. You pass the address of the `argsCount` function argument to `argc`. An address on a typical commodity platform/OS like amd64/Windows is an insanely huge value—if interpreted as a count.

   My bet is that the function crashes when it makes an attempt to read that many elements from `argv`—causing it to read memory your process had not mapped.
3. Two problems here:

   1. Passing an address of a slice value as an argument expecting the address of the first element of that slice is wrong.

      This is because a slice value (presently, in the "reference" Go implementation you're supposedly using) is a `struct` with 3 fields: an address of the underlying data array, the number of elements in that array allowed to be used and the total count of such elements in that array which may be used without reallocation by the `append` function when called on the slice value.

      When you have `args []string` and do `&args` you get the address of that structure, not the address of the first element of that slice.

      To do the latter, use `&args[0]`.
   2. In Go, a string (typically, and let's assume that's the case) contains characters encoded as UTF-8. This is typically not what a Windows-native C++ code expects to deal with when it says it wants a `char *`.

      My guess, you need to first construct a proper thing for the `argv`,
      something like

      ```golang
      argv := make([]unsafe.Pointer, 0, len(args))
      for i, s := range args {
          argv[i] = unsafe.Pointer(syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr(s))
      }
      ```

      and then pass `&argv[0]` to the callee.

      But see below for `syscall.StringToUTF16Ptr()`.
4. The preparation you're doing to pass string data to the rest of the arguments which have the `const char*` type appears to be correct but only if the callee really means its `char` is a 16-bit integer.

   In other words, the source code *and the toolchain* used to compile that library must have made sure that `char` was really [`wchar_t` or `WCHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/working-with-strings).

   If yes, what you do should be OK; otherwise it's not. You should verify this.

#### A note on passing `uintptr`s across expressions

Go features garbage collection, and because of this its runtime must know all pointers to all currently live objects. As long as there exists a variable containing a pointer to a memory block allocated during the program run time, that block won't be garbage-collected.

An `unsafe.Pointer` value counts as a proper reference to a memory block *but an `uintptr` value **is not.*** This means when the code

```golang
p := new(someType)
u := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&p))
foo(u)
return
```

is running, the GC is free to reclaim the object allocated by `p` as soon as `p` was assigned its address—simply because `p` is the sole reference to that object, and `u` is not.

Now consider that the GC in the reference Go implementation runs concurrently with the code of your program.
This means when `foo` runs, so may do the GC, and it may sweep your instance of `someType` right from under the feet of `foo`.

As an exception to this general rule, the Go compiler guarantees that all the `uintptr(unsafe.Pointer)` type conversions occuring in the same *language expression* are immune to the GC. So taking our previous example, it's OK to do

```golang
foo(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(new(someType)))
return
```

and

```golang
p := new(someType)
v := unsafe.Pointer(&p)
foo(uintptr(v))
return
```

since the type-conversion to `uintptr` happens in a single expression—which is a function call.

As a consequence, you must not pass pointers to Go objects around as `uintptr`s *unless* they contain pointers obtained from the "C side".

Comment: Pretty late, I know. However, 4. probably is little helpful, rather misleading. Sure, 16-bit char systems *do* exist, but they are pretty rare and the DLL most likely has not been written for such a system. Instead, the function would rather expect 8-bit bytes, thus we'd instead need a function like (the not existing) `syscall.UTF8PtrFromString`.

Comment: Something like `b := []byte(myString); b = append(b, 0); ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&b[0])` to have `syscall.Syscall(..., uintptr(ptr), ...)` – if the DLL cannot cope with utf-8 (not a matter, if only ASCII contained anyway) we yet might have to convert encoding to local system's one.

Comment: @Aconcagua, it actually exists in the form of `C.CString`, but only when using `cgo` ;-) Yes, you're correct in that I should have probably put more variants offered by guesseneering into my response, but unfortunately there's too little known about the DLL. After all, `const char*` might in that API really _mean_ a type-puned pointer to `uint16_t`-s or something like this. 

Comment: `char` in C or C++ is a language type just like `int` in go and maps to the target's smallest addressable unit, which typically is a 8-bit byte, but *can* be larger (then no `uint8_t` would exist either). Compilers usually allow to specify signedness of, never heard of they allow to change size – and would not be recommendable either, would break any expectations of developers on that system... *'It* might *mean [...]'* – yes, if we are on a system with 16-bit smallest addressable unit. Honestly, someone coding on such exotic systems I'd really expect to get *this* matter right alone ;)

Comment: No critisism, though. Just a small detail that could be written better. Apart from, appreciated the answer, contained some nice details interesting to know (still go beginner...).

Comment: @Aconcagua, ah, no, bad wording on my part! I meant that in C, `char *` might mean a pointer to _anything._ Some programmers "feel" like using `void*` is somehow too vague and using `char*` to point to a "contiguous lump of data" is somehow better. So really without further knowledge about what the DLLs author really meant (does the function "under the hood" treats the pointer as an address of a series of 16-bit values), guessing is only so much good, unfortunately. BTW, I appreciate your mentioning of non-UTF-8 legacy system encodings—this is definitely a possibility.

Comment: OK, such usage is known to me – although I disagree (consider e. g. `memset`, `memcpy`, ... – but that's another topic). I wouldn't expect this here, though: There are no lengths given anywhere, so I'd assume 0-terminated sequences, and `int argc, char* argv[]` ressembles pretty much C's `main` function (one legal variant of, at least), which expects ordinary c-strings, too.

Comment: Representing an expected sequence of 16-bit values with `char*` would be pretty strange, too, as there are better options (preferrably `uint16_t*`, but with `CHAR_BIT == 8` e. g. `unsigned shor*`, possibly `wchar_t*` or `char16_t*`, should just be as fine, even though not *guaranteeing* 16 bit...). – `cgo`'s `CString` is nice, by the way, and would be absolutely appropriate here, as we are coding against a C library anyway (well, says C++, but I'd asume `extern "C"` functions here to avoid name mangling...).