# How to use NewLazyDLL (golang) to custom dll export from c# to set parameters

Tags: windows, go, dll, ffi

I wrote a custom dll export in c# which is working in c

This is my c# code for dll export

```
[DllExport]
/* GetMSLResult from the parameter as lat, lon, and gps elevation */
public static double GetMSLResult(IntPtr lat, IntPtr lon, IntPtr gpsElevation) => Helper.GetMSL(Helper.GetGeoID(Helper.IntPtrToDouble(lat), Helper.IntPtrToDouble(lon)), Helper.IntPtrToDouble(gpsElevation));
```

which is working and expose via

```
dumpbin /exports ClassLibrary1.dll

Which has my procedure is present
```

Also as i test in c code its working as well
this is my

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef int(*GetMSLResult)(const wchar_t* str, const wchar_t* str1);

int main()
{
    auto dll = ::LoadLibrary(L"ClassLibrary1.dll");   // さっき作ったC# DLLの名前を指定する
    {
        auto result = reinterpret_cast<GetMSLResult>(::GetProcAddress(dll, "Count"));
        wcout << result(L"34.00", L"40.00") << endl; // this returns 74.00
        wcout << result(L"90.00", L"40.00") << endl; // this returns 130.00


    }
    if ( dll )
        ::FreeLibrary(dll); // 解放は忘れずに！！

    return 0;
}
```

this is working successfully, in golang i created a test code to read the exported dll not imported dll.

I wrote a simple test in windows how to do it but it seems i got an error and exited when i try to call the function i want to return the value

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    h := syscall.NewLazyDLL("ClassLibrary1.dll")
    proc := h.NewProc("GetGeoID")

    a := string("32.00")

    n, _, _ := proc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&a))) 

    //fmt.Printf("teast  %v", n)
    fmt.Printf("Hello dll function returns %d\n", n)
}
```

Currently this is my golang code.

In my GeoID expected two parameter which is lattitude and longitude

so in my code in golang

```
a := string("32.00")
b := string("32.00")

i want this to pass the parameter a and b to my dll procedure functions
so that i could be able to get a result.

n, _, _ := proc.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&a)))
```

But currently i received this error

```
Exception 0xe0434352 0x80131537 0x0 0x766afd62
PC=0x766afd62

syscall.Syscall(0x6e35290e, 0x1, 0x11006108, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/syscall_windows.go:184 +0xbb
syscall.(*Proc).Call(0x11004100, 0x110120e0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x10, 0x4907e0, 0x1, 0x110120e0)
        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:171 +0x10a
syscall.(*LazyProc).Call(0x11049aa0, 0x110120e0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x44bc01, 0x11034000, 0x11034000)
        C:/Go/src/syscall/dll_windows.go:333 +0x48
main.main()
        C:/Users/christopher/developer/go/src/gotest/main.go:16 +0x103
eax     0x19fbc0
ebx     0x5
ecx     0x5
edx     0x0
edi     0x1
esi     0x19fc80
ebp     0x19fc18
esp     0x19fbc0
eip     0x766afd62
eflags  0x216
cs      0x23
fs      0x53
gs      0x2b
exit status 2
```

Is there any good way i can call my custom dll procedure or function
like GetAge(34, 56) and the result in golang? currently ive been using LoadDLL, NewLazyDLL and other stuff but i could not be able to achieve my goal, does somebody can suggest a good way to do it?

Comment: You're calling your function in a wrong way. To not repeat myself, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56755969/720999) I explained to some other gopher how to go about passing strings to C API on Windows. Basically, two points: 1) in Go, taking an address of a string variable is not the same as taking an address of the first byte of the data stored in it; 2) Your C++ example uses `wchar_t` which these days usually means UTF-16 on Windows, while Go strings are normally UTF-8-encoded. (On a side note that you did not test your DLL "in c code", you did it with C++.)

Comment: thank you very much for spending time to check my post i really wanted to test the dll if its really work in golang but on c++ it seems working fine which i can see as no problem for it for the golang i dont understand why it cannot the return value from the procedure but it seems difficult to manage via golang. I tried available dll reader like loaddll or library etc but it doesnt give me the exact values i want to do

Comment: I honestly fail to see what your comment adds to what was already stated by the question. Your Go code fails because you ostensibly did at least two errors while trying to set up arguments to pass to your function call. I pointed at these problems and linked an answer which goes in deep details on both points. If you want to get your problem sorted, I advise you to actually go and research the linked answer and adjusting your code accordingly.